# Drupal "HTTP request status Fails" error

Tags: php, http, drupal, drupal-7

I am getting a drupal error on status report.

**The Error:**

> HTTPRL - Core drupal_http_request() Your system or network
>   configuration does not allow Drupal to access web pages. This could be
>   due to your webserver configuration or PHP settings.

**The Debug info:**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [count] => 1
                    [time] => 6770.18
                    [mode] => 2
                    [blocking] => FALSE
                    [url] => http://www.ihouseu.com/httprl_async_function_callback?count=1
                    [request] => Array (
                            [http://www.ihouseu.com/httprl_async_function_callback?count=1] => stdClass Object (
                                    [url] => http://www.ihouseu.com/httprl_async_function_callback?count=1
                                    [status] => Non-Blocking request sent out. Not waiting for the response.
                                    [code] => 0
                                    [chunk_size] => 1024
                                    [data] => 
                                    [request] => POST /httprl_async_function_callback?count=1 HTTP/1.0
Host: www.ihouseu.com
Connection: closed
User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 554

master_key=d77599a44350a426f3f0eae50fb9dd3d1aa16ea97d48d3262407db6af8f27e205e0416a5e9d44e515329261adf6267184a886e578848a38f70e3d4b3694cea59&temp_key=httprl_a746459f3363a5ddf1f55c5361ada1c3e328930ce948cfe55fd4add3cd4d24302efe39ef588b333e7199c50956437c09c11e1f06e1128a4d5136a7e2c84bad05&mode=0&php_timeout=120&function=httprl_lock_release&args=YToxOntpOjA7czoxMzU6Imh0dHBybF9mZmE2NDc0ZDVjZmQwZDBmZjFhNzRlNWM3M2Q0ZTg3OWE1MDZkYTEwNDMwNzcyZmM1OTk3NTllNzA2ZTM0ZGM0YzJkYTQ4Y2MyNmQ2M2JmN2FjNWEzZjUxNjUxMjJkMGJlN2IzZjc1NzYwOWMzMTJhZmVjNmNkODNkOTM0Y2U4YSI7fQ%3D%3D
                                    [options] => Array (
                                            [data] => master_key=d77599a44350a426f3f0eae50fb9dd3d1aa16ea97d48d3262407db6af8f27e205e0416a5e9d44e515329261adf6267184a886e578848a38f70e3d4b3694cea59&temp_key=httprl_a746459f3363a5ddf1f55c5361ada1c3e328930ce948cfe55fd4add3cd4d24302efe39ef588b333e7199c50956437c09c11e1f06e1128a4d5136a7e2c84bad05&mode=0&php_timeout=120&function=httprl_lock_release&args=YToxOntpOjA7czoxMzU6Imh0dHBybF9mZmE2NDc0ZDVjZmQwZDBmZjFhNzRlNWM3M2Q0ZTg3OWE1MDZkYTEwNDMwNzcyZmM1OTk3NTllNzA2ZTM0ZGM0YzJkYTQ4Y2MyNmQ2M2JmN2FjNWEzZjUxNjUxMjJkMGJlN2IzZjc1NzYwOWMzMTJhZmVjNmNkODNkOTM0Y2U4YSI7fQ%3D%3D
                                            [internal_states] => Array (
                                                    [background_function_return] => 
                                                    [background_function_args] => Array (
                                                            [0] => httprl_ffa6474d5cfd0d0ff1a74e5c73d4e879a506da10430772fc599759e706e34dc4c2da48cc26d63bf7ac5a3f5165122d0be7b3f757609c312afec6cd83d934ce8a
                                                        )
                                                )
                                            [blocking] => 
                                            [method] => POST
                                            [timeout] => 6.99989199638
                                            [max_redirects] => 0
                                            [headers] => Array (
                                                    [Host] => www.ihouseu.com
                                                    [Connection] => closed
                                                    [User-Agent] => Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)
                                                    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                                                    [Content-Length] => 554
                                                )
                                            [lock_name] => httprl_a746459f3363a5ddf1f55c5361ada1c3e328930ce948cfe55fd4add3cd4d24302efe39ef588b333e7199c50956437c09c11e1f06e1128a4d5136a7e2c84bad05
                                            [dns_timeout] => 5
                                            [connect_timeout] => 30
                                            [ttfb_timeout] => 20
                                            [context] => 
                                            [secure_socket_transport] => ssl
                                            [version] => 1.0
                                            [referrer] => 
                                            [domain_connections] => 2
                                            [global_connections] => 128
                                            [global_timeout] => 120
                                            [chunk_size_read] => 32768
                                            [chunk_size_write] => 1024
                                            [async_connect] => 1
                                            [ping_db] => 20
                                            [data-input] => Array (
                                                    [master_key] => d77599a44350a426f3f0eae50fb9dd3d1aa16ea97d48d3262407db6af8f27e205e0416a5e9d44e515329261adf6267184a886e578848a38f70e3d4b3694cea59
                                                    [temp_key] => httprl_a746459f3363a5ddf1f55c5361ada1c3e328930ce948cfe55fd4add3cd4d24302efe39ef588b333e7199c50956437c09c11e1f06e1128a4d5136a7e2c84bad05
                                                    [mode] => 
                                                    [php_timeout] => 120
                                                    [function] => httprl_lock_release
                                                    [context] => Array (
                                                        )
                                                    [args] => YToxOntpOjA7czoxMzU6Imh0dHBybF9mZmE2NDc0ZDVjZmQwZDBmZjFhNzRlNWM3M2Q0ZTg3OWE1MDZkYTEwNDMwNzcyZmM1OTk3NTllNzA2ZTM0ZGM0YzJkYTQ4Y2MyNmQ2M2JmN2FjNWEzZjUxNjUxMjJkMGJlN2IzZjc1NzYwOWMzMTJhZmVjNmNkODNkOTM0Y2U4YSI7fQ==
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [socket] => tcp://www.ihouseu.com:80
                                    [flags] => 6
                                    [uri] => Array (
                                            [scheme] => http
                                            [host] => www.ihouseu.com
                                            [path] => /httprl_async_function_callback
                                            [query] => count=1
                                        )
                                    [running_time] => 0.000108003616333
                                    [fp] => Resource id #2337
                                    [bytes_sent] => 0
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [count] => 1
                    [time] => 7040.89
                    [mode] => 2
                    [blocking] => TRUE
                    [url] => http://www.ihouseu.com/httprl_async_function_callback?count=2
                    [request] => Array (
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array (
                    [count] => 1
                    [time] => 6888.28
                    [mode] => 1
                    [blocking] => FALSE
                    [url] => http://www.ihouseu.com/httprl_async_function_callback?count=0
                    [request] => stdClass Object (
                            [__original_class_name__] => stdClass
                            [url] => http://www.ihouseu.com/httprl_async_function_callback?count=0
                            [status] => Done.
                            [code] => 200
                            [chunk_size] => 32768
                            [data] => 0=YTozOntzOjY6InJldHVybiI7TjtzOjQ6ImFyZ3MiO2E6MTp7aTowO3M6MTM1OiJodHRwcmxfNTQ5ODRlMjk3NmRhZTZkNjYxZWRhOTRjNTg0ZmUyNzI0YjQzMGFlNDVmZjFiYTU2YmVkNDdmZTRhYzhjMDZlZDhhZjBkN2EyN2Q4NzkyNGIyZGYyNmJhNjdjZmI2N2FlOTJhYjAyMTgxNGJiNWFhMDBmMGI4NTIyNmY4MDViMzkiO31zOjc6InByaW50ZWQiO3M6MDoiIjt9
                            [request] => POST /httprl_async_function_callback?count=0 HTTP/1.0
Host: www.ihouseu.com
Connection: closed
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 552
User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)

master_key=d77599a44350a426f3f0eae50fb9dd3d1aa16ea97d48d3262407db6af8f27e205e0416a5e9d44e515329261adf6267184a886e578848a38f70e3d4b3694cea59&temp_key=httprl_5e764a8fdf5fd0cc0765d865c11f4cd16ec4f62e26cbcda848fc9fddd3ea81d19036e570ef3efa9123606f0a8aa03d96f71a1e6ae8b3341da303a5a1a1e6be1d&mode=1&php_timeout=7&function=httprl_lock_release&args=YToxOntpOjA7czoxMzU6Imh0dHBybF81NDk4NGUyOTc2ZGFlNmQ2NjFlZGE5NGM1ODRmZTI3MjRiNDMwYWU0NWZmMWJhNTZiZWQ0N2ZlNGFjOGMwNmVkOGFmMGQ3YTI3ZDg3OTI0YjJkZjI2YmE2N2NmYjY3YWU5MmFiMDIxODE0YmI1YWEwMGYwYjg1MjI2ZjgwNWIzOSI7fQ%3D%3D
                            [options] => Array (
                                    [data] => master_key=d77599a44350a426f3f0eae50fb9dd3d1aa16ea97d48d3262407db6af8f27e205e0416a5e9d44e515329261adf6267184a886e578848a38f70e3d4b3694cea59&temp_key=httprl_5e764a8fdf5fd0cc0765d865c11f4cd16ec4f62e26cbcda848fc9fddd3ea81d19036e570ef3efa9123606f0a8aa03d96f71a1e6ae8b3341da303a5a1a1e6be1d&mode=1&php_timeout=7&function=httprl_lock_release&args=YToxOntpOjA7czoxMzU6Imh0dHBybF81NDk4NGUyOTc2ZGFlNmQ2NjFlZGE5NGM1ODRmZTI3MjRiNDMwYWU0NWZmMWJhNTZiZWQ0N2ZlNGFjOGMwNmVkOGFmMGQ3YTI3ZDg3OTI0YjJkZjI2YmE2N2NmYjY3YWU5MmFiMDIxODE0YmI1YWEwMGYwYjg1MjI2ZjgwNWIzOSI7fQ%3D%3D
                                    [method] => POST
                                    [headers] => Array (
                                            [Host] => www.ihouseu.com
                                            [Connection] => closed
                                            [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                                            [Content-Length] => 552
                                            [User-Agent] => Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)
                                        )
                                    [timeout] => 6.86747908592
                                    [max_redirects] => 0
                                    [data-input] => Array (
                                            [master_key] => d77599a44350a426f3f0eae50fb9dd3d1aa16ea97d48d3262407db6af8f27e205e0416a5e9d44e515329261adf6267184a886e578848a38f70e3d4b3694cea59
                                            [temp_key] => httprl_5e764a8fdf5fd0cc0765d865c11f4cd16ec4f62e26cbcda848fc9fddd3ea81d19036e570ef3efa9123606f0a8aa03d96f71a1e6ae8b3341da303a5a1a1e6be1d
                                            [mode] => 1
                                            [php_timeout] => 7
                                            [function] => httprl_lock_release
                                            [args] => YToxOntpOjA7czoxMzU6Imh0dHBybF81NDk4NGUyOTc2ZGFlNmQ2NjFlZGE5NGM1ODRmZTI3MjRiNDMwYWU0NWZmMWJhNTZiZWQ0N2ZlNGFjOGMwNmVkOGFmMGQ3YTI3ZDg3OTI0YjJkZjI2YmE2N2NmYjY3YWU5MmFiMDIxODE0YmI1YWEwMGYwYjg1MjI2ZjgwNWIzOSI7fQ==
                                        )
                                    [dns_timeout] => 5
                                    [connect_timeout] => 30
                                    [ttfb_timeout] => 20
                                    [context] => 
                                    [secure_socket_transport] => ssl
                                    [blocking] => 1
                                    [version] => 1.0
                                    [referrer] => 
                                    [domain_connections] => 2
                                    [global_connections] => 128
                                    [global_timeout] => 120
                                    [chunk_size_read] => 32768
                                    [chunk_size_write] => 1024
                                    [async_connect] => 1
                                    [ping_db] => 20
                                )
                            [socket] => tcp://www.ihouseu.com:80
                            [flags] => 6
                            [uri] => Array (
                                    [scheme] => http
                                    [host] => www.ihouseu.com
                                    [path] => /httprl_async_function_callback
                                    [query] => count=0
                                )
                            [running_time] => 0.132520914078
                            [fp] => Resource id #2339
                            [bytes_sent] => 764
                            [time_to_first_byte] => 0.132577896118
                            [protocol] => HTTP/1.1
                            [status_message] => OK
                            [headers] => Array (
                                    [date] => Sun, 26 Apr 2015 21:03:54 GMT
                                    [server] => Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6
                                    [x-powered-by] => PHP/5.4.39
                                    [x-drupal-cache] => MISS
                                    [expires] => Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
                                    [cache-control] => no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
                                    [connection] => close
                                    [content-type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => TRUE
)
```

What I tried:

- Added a hostname entry on /etc/hosts file for my site.
- Added these lines on my settings.php:

`$conf['drupal_http_request_fails'] = FALSE;<br>`

`$conf['assume_http_request_works'] = TRUE;`

**System Details:**

OS: Centos 6.6
Server Software: Cpanel/WHM
PHP version: 5.4.39
Apache version: 2.2.29
Drupal Version: 7.36

**On php.ini**

> allow_url_fopen = On 
>   allow_url_include = On 
>   disable_functions =  none

Tried clearing cache every time does not work .
And php handler is php-fpm .

Looking forward for a solution guys !
Thanks

Comment: I'm having this myself for a few days now, and from searches on the web and the Drupal website I see more messages from recent days (as well as older ones which were partly resolved). Maybe something is going on with a recent Drupal update.

Comment: Hmm. My issue had something to do with my Nginx configuration (the query parameter did not work with rewrite URL properly). As you use Apache I guess I can't offer any help.